# Modelsim signal declaration issue

Tags: signals, fpga, modelsim

With Modelsim I would like to test a code but one signal always remains uninitialized. Here a code snipped to explain the problem with Modelsim:

```
-- Signal Declaration
signal shifter          : std_logic_vector(0 to 6);
signal led_out_temp         : std_logic;    


process (reset_reset_n) is
begin
    if reset_reset_n = '0' then
        shifter <= (others => '0');  -- After reset_reset_n goes to '0' shifter is '0000000'
        led_out_temp <= '0';         -- Always has the value 'U'
    end if;
end process;
```

When I step through it I can check the values but even after stepping out of the process the signal **"led_out_temp" is 'U'**. Can someone tell me why?

Thanks!

Comment: This minimal example is not complete. Can you provide a full testbench? Your process is a combinatorical process, so `led_out_temp` has a latch behavior.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to duplicate the problem, it's not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  A  common cause of `'U' values is multiple drivers one with a default value of 'U'.

Comment: that question should closed. adding a bounty doesn't make it a better question.
The is not enough information to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible methods to check the design

1. Write a testbench where you assign reset_reset_n to zero
2. Simulate the design in Modelsim without a testbench and force the value of reset_reset_n to zero before running the simulation

Is *shifter* becoming zero in your try? If it's also not going to zero, then you might not have gone inside the *if* loop.

**[Edit: Including sample testbench format]**

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY test_tb IS
END test_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF test_tb IS

   -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    COMPONENT name_of_your_design
    PORT(
         reset_reset_n : IN  std_logic;
         input2 : IN  std_logic
         output : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        );
    END COMPONENT;

   -- Signal initializations
   signal reset_reset_n_sig : std_logic := '0';
   signal input2_sig : std_logic := '0';
   signal output_sig : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

BEGIN

    -- Port mapping
   instance_name: name_of_your_design PORT MAP (
         reset_reset_n => reset_reset_n_sig
         input2  => input2_sig,
         ouput => output_sig
        );

  -- Give your test inputs here
  process_to_give_test_inputs: process
   begin        
        wait for 7 ns;
        reset_reset_n <='1';
        wait for 3 ns;
        reset_reset_n <='0';
        wait;
  end process;

END;
```

Ref: https://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2011/06/vhdl-code-for-4-tap-fir-filter.html

Thanks: @morteza kavakebi

Comment: A process that assigns a signal has a driver for that signal. All it's drivers are resolved using a package std_logic_1164 resolution function. Resolution  can return a 'U' for several reasons, which one can't be determined from the OP's snippet and adding a bounty doesn't help. The OP hasn't participated since Apr 5, 2019 and didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your answer's included code doesn't appear useful. Asking a question in an answer is usually an indication the Original Post has quality issues affecting it's value as a search resource for those with similar problems. See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). Your bounty appears to serve no useful without the OP's further participation. You could ask your own specific programming question while providing enough detail to answer. Failing that Stackoverflow search with terms *[vhdl] driver effective resolved*.

Comment: Waiting for a better answer. I have enabled a bounty of 100, expiring soon